# How to interpret odds ratios by emmeans for glmmTMB-beta

Tags: odds-ratio, beta-distribution, lsmeans, glmmtmb

I fit this mixed model with beta for the response variable: photochemical efficiency or Fv/Fm and the predictor variables are categorical:

```
Family: beta  ( logit )
Formula:          FvFm ~ hora * temperatura + (1 | Experimento)
Data: d

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  -730.4   -711.2    371.2   -742.4      174 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups      Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Experimento (Intercept) 0.0099   0.0995  
Number of obs: 180, groups:  Experimento, 5

Dispersion parameter for beta family ():  262 

Conditional model:
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)          0.26960    0.04821    5.59 2.24e-08 ***
hora4                0.03181    0.02627    1.21   0.2260    
temperatura20        0.05626    0.02630    2.14   0.0324 *  
hora4:temperatura20 -1.44971    0.03859  -37.56  < 2e-16 ***
```

I have been trying to interpret a posteriori test, emmeans results with type="response", so I get the odds ratios (exp) of the estimated marginal means for all possible comparison groups.

```
> emmGrid<-emmeans(m2, specs=pairwise~temperatura*hora, type="response")
> emmGrid
$emmeans
 temperatura hora response      SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 2           0       0.567 0.01184 Inf     0.544     0.590
 20          0       0.581 0.01175 Inf     0.558     0.604
 2           4       0.575 0.01179 Inf     0.552     0.598
 20          4       0.251 0.00928 Inf     0.233     0.270

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the logit scale 

$contrasts
 contrast                                  odds.ratio     SE  df null z.ratio p.value
 temperatura2 hora0 / temperatura20 hora0       0.945 0.0249 Inf    1  -2.139  0.1408
 temperatura2 hora0 / temperatura2 hora4        0.969 0.0254 Inf    1  -1.211  0.6200
 temperatura2 hora0 / temperatura20 hora4       3.903 0.1101 Inf    1  48.268  <.0001
 temperatura20 hora0 / temperatura2 hora4       1.025 0.0270 Inf    1   0.929  0.7894
 temperatura20 hora0 / temperatura20 hora4      4.128 0.1167 Inf    1  50.149  <.0001
 temperatura2 hora4 / temperatura20 hora4       4.029 0.1138 Inf    1  49.346  <.0001

P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates 
Tests are performed on the log odds ratio scale
```

I have doubts about this: 1-Is it ok to do this test for glmmtmb beta? 2-if it is possible: how to interpret these odd. ratios?, from what I have read I understand that an odd ratio of 1 indicates no change therefore for odds.ratio close to 4 will indicate that it is four times more likely to occur, only those are significant. 3-odd ratio as shown below the output is in logit scale? Thank you very much!!, any ideas, please post... fran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going over each of your questions:

**Is it ok to do this test for glmmtmb beta?**
I've never used this combination myself but most likely yes. `glmmTMB` fits GLMMs via standard maximum likelihood and the fact that `emmeans` knows what to do with those objects makes me relatively confident that the estimates are accurate.

**How to interpret these odd. ratios?** First, recall that odds are a transformation of a risk or probability $p$ via $odds=p/(1-p)$. As probability increases so do odds, but their proportion is not linear. You are correct that an odds ratio > 1 means higher odds (and thereby higher probability) and < 1 is the opposite, but the nuance I want to make is that an odds ratio of 4 is not 4 times the *risk*, it is higher *odds*. You need a baseline risk to convert that into a risk ratio, and usually odds ratios are larger than risk ratios (but that depends on the absolute value of the risk involved).

**Odd ratio as shown below the output is in logit scale?** No, an odds ratio implies it was back-transformed from the log-odds scale. Only inference was generated in that scale, and back-transformed where indicated. In addition you requested marginal means in the response scale, so those are in fact probabilities (or risks).

As a sanity check you can manually calculate some of the parameters yourself: risk at `temperatura2 hora4` is $0.575$ (odds $\approx 1.353$), at `temperatura20 hora4` it is $0.251$ (odds $\approx 0.335$). Their ratio is $\approx 4.037$ which matches the contrast reasonably well. To restate my above point note that the *risk* ratio is only $\approx 2.291$.

Comment: Thanks @PBulls, consult how did you calculate the risk ratio??

Comment: By simply dividing the observed responses, i.e. $0.575/0.251$. I'm not sure how you'd go about getting a standard error or confidence interval for this quantity from such model though.